# the world of MDX queries

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, cube

I am looking for SSAS cube and MDX (Multidimensional Expressions) sites like our StackOverflow site.

Any other resources for SSAS cubes would be welcome as well.

Comment: By "SO" do you mean "Stack Overflow"?

Comment: yup. SO = Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [official Microsoft forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/threads)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, but anything by Mosha Pasumansky (creator of MDX) is a must:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/default.aspx

Comment: The blog states he left the BI industry in 2009 to focus on the search engine bing.